# Making a div the same size as an image inside it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have an div with the following code

HTML:

```
<div id='imgContainer'>
    <img src='/img/logo.png' id='imglogo'></img>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#imgContainer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 13px;
}
```

The problem is the users can edit the image size, colour and some other things, so I want the div to get bigger as the image get bigger. I want the width and height of the div to be 250px if the image is smaller than it, but to get bigger as the image gets bigger.

The solution can be in PHP, JavaScript, CSS or jQuery.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
div#imgContainer {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2c99/1/)

Thanks to @ahren and @Mohsen

Comment: Why `display:inline`? It's the only thing preventing me from upvoting this answer... The way should be `inline-block` (as mentioned below) - but it should also come with a disclaimer that it won't work in old IE.

Comment: must be `display:inline-block`

Comment: I tried this first because it looks right, but why do you need the property display: inline-block? Is it kind of a hack? It still works.

Comment: @Me123 because without `inline-block` div width will stretch according to containers width (sorry for my english :)), try removing it on fiddle, and you'll see the result

Comment: if you add a solid 1px border to the div you will see that there is a gap below the image. The div does not properly contain the image

Answer (score 2):

Does floating the div work with your layout? This will cause its width to wrap to the contained image.

```
div#imgContainer {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 13px;
    float: left;
}
```

If you need to clear it, add a wrapping element with `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the work:

```
div{
    border:1px solid black;  /* you can remove this */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* you can remove this */
    padding:13px;
    min-width:250px;
    min-height:250px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

So either use float on your div or just use display:inline-block manually.

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/mxykW/

Comment: Thanks hRvoed, but @karaxuna already answered the same a while ago.

Comment: Ups, I see, sorry, he was faster

Comment: plus one for making the image a block to get rid of the gap at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

php is very usefull in this, as it has the '[getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)' function:

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize($filename);
$fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
if ($size && $fp) {
    header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
} else {
    // error
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't able to test it as my apache is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#imgContainer {
    min-height: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    width: Auto;
    height: Auto;
    padding: 13px;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to set `width` and `height` auto.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
div#imgContainer {
    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 13px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but also the same as karaxuna's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to do like this:

```
div#imgContainer {
    width: Auto;
    height: Auto;
    padding: 13px;
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to specify the `width` or `height`, as the `auto` value is the one by default. Only in case the div is inheriting styles.

Comment: Yes, but what if the image is smaller than 250px. Then the the div must stay 250px.

Comment: then use `min-width: 250px;`

Comment: What if image is smaller than that?

Comment: I was giving a possibility for @Me123 comment