# How to make this css3 slider responsive

Tags: css, slider, responsive

I found this smooth and simple code for a pure css3 slideshow... problem is, it isn't responsive because the parent div "slider" stays at 470px when the images get smaller with a smaller screensize. Images are already responsive like a charm when adding width: 100%. Someone an idea? Is it even possible?

HTML:

```
<div class='slider'>
<div class='slide1'><img src="../lp-pic-first.png"></div>
<div class='slide2'><img src="../lp-pic-second.png"></div>
<div class='slide3'><img src="../lp-pic-four.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
max-width: 1175px;
height: 470px;
position: relative;
width: 94%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {

animation:fade 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 16s infinite;

}
.slide2 {

animation:fade2 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 16s infinite;
}

.slide3 {

animation:fade3 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 16s infinite;
}



@keyframes fade
{
0%   {opacity:1}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 1}
66.666% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 1}
100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to maintain the aspect ratio of the slideshow as it gets bigger or smaller, there’s a couple ways you can do this.

One is to use vw units for the width and height of the container. For example:

```
.slider {
  height: 48vw; /* 48/27 = 1.777 (16:9 aspect ratio) */
  height: 27vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Another way is to add another wrapper around the whole thing and give the inner part a padding-bottom value set to the aspect ratio you want. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class='slider'>
<div class='slide1'><img src="../lp-pic-first.png"></div>
<div class='slide2'><img src="../lp-pic-second.png"></div>
<div class='slide3'><img src="../lp-pic-four.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 470px;
    width: 94%;
    max-width: 1175px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.slider {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 9/16 = 0.5625 (16:9 aspect ratio) */
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, but perhaps I mis-explained it - the images are not the problem, the slider-div, which stays at 470 px (or 29.375em or whatever) while the images adapt to the screensize. Result is, that there is a div with a height of 470px that shows an image with a half as high sized image. Tested your solutions, but none solved this :/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class `img-responsive` to the `img` tag. Rest of your code remains the same. This will change the size of the image according to your screen size.

```css
.slider {
max-width: 1175px;
height: 470px;
position: relative;
width: 94%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide1,.slide2,.slide3,.slide4,.slide5 {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {

animation:fade 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 16s infinite;

}
.slide2 {

animation:fade2 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 16s infinite;
}

.slide3 {

animation:fade3 16s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade3 16s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
0%   {opacity:1}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 0}
100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 1}
66.666% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0}
}
@keyframes fade3
{
0%   {opacity:0}
33.333% { opacity: 0}
66.666% { opacity: 1}
100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container"> 
<div class='slider'>
<div class='slide1'><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-2.jpg"></div>
<div class='slide2'><img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-5.jpg"></div>
<div class='slide3'><img class="img-responsive" src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-5/data/images/sur.jpg"></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, but perhaps I mis-explained it - the images are not the problem, the slider-div, which stays at 470 px (or 29.375em or whatever) while the images adapt to the screensize.

Comment: You want to decrease the height of the div according to the screen size?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but when I give it a relative height the absolute-positioned sub-divs dont fit anymore.

Comment: You have given ``height:100%`` to the slide1, 2 and 3. Remove that and add ``display:inline-block``. This will work. For details: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242962/making-a-div-the-same-size-as-an-image-inside-it)

Comment: Thank you Shalinee!

Comment: I can't, because it's a comment - or how can I flag comments as answers that solved the problem?